Gizmo away from the object in FreeCAD
I downloaded a Mecanum wheel model from grabcad but its Gizmo is away from the Object. Is there any way to correct it? I tried Changing "Position" under "Placement" but its returning back to where it was after some time. Also this technique is prone to minor misalignment. How can i bring the gizmo back to center of mass?

